# show image from std::vector<uint8_t> into QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.1

i want to show jpeg data from my vector to QGraphicsView so thid is my code :

```
void StatusWindow::onThumbPicsChanged(std::map<std::string, std::vector<uint8_t>> files)
{

  QPixmap p;

  p.loadFromData(QByteArray((char *)(files["c@jpg"].data())),"jpg");
// pointers are valid 
  ui->graphicsViewColor->scene()->addPixmap(p);
}
```

but nothing display

what's wrong

Comment: Did you check that ui->graphicsViewColor->scene() is a non null pointer ?

Comment: i edited the question. pointer are valid main problem is nothing display . access violation was because of another problem

Comment: Not related to the problem, but it could be a good ideia to pass `files` as a reference (`std::map<std::string, std::vector<uint8_t>> files`). It can save (problably) a lot of work avoiding `std::map` copies.